# Knockout with jQuery binding handler for hover background colour change not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, hover, knockout.js

I've created a custom binding handler with knockout that works in Chrome and Firefox, but unfortunately not in IE8. Its purpose is to change the background colour of an element when the user has hovered the mouse over it. It also sets the background colour (not just on mouse hover) when the data bound to that element is "selected", but if it becomes unselected the element should go back to its original background colour.

In IE8 the elements don't go back to the original colour (can't unselect) as illustrated by [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbTtr/5/). Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This could be solved more easily using just css :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was very silly - I was using the shorthand 'background' in $e.css('background') instead of 'background-color'.